# jQuery Accordion - Cannot close current <dt>

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Below is simple jQuery Accordion :

```
(function ($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () {
        allPanels.slideUp();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });

})(jQuery);

<dl class="accordion">
<dt><a href="">Panel 1</a></dt>

    <dd>Pellentesque fermentum dolor. Aliquam quam lectus, facilisis auctor, ultrices ut, elementum vulputate, nunc.</dd>
<dt><a href="">Panel 2</a></dt>

    <dd>Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</dd>
<dt><a href="">Panel 3</a></dt>

    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Phasellus hendrerit. Pellentesque aliquet nibh nec urna. In nisi neque, aliquet vel, dapibus id, mattis vel, nisi. Sed pretium, ligula sollicitudin laoreet viverra, tortor libero sodales leo, eget blandit nunc tortor eu nibh. Nullam mollis. Ut justo. Suspendisse potenti.</dd>
</dl>
```

the problem is when you click Panel 1, `<dd>` will expend but if you click again to closed it(Panel 1), `<dd>` will hide and expend again. This is wrong, it should be closed if user click Panel 1 again, so how to close `<dd>` if tab is open ?

JSFiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/b4g9U/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the line `allPanels.slideUp()`, you should ignore the current panel from this operation

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

    $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () {
        var $target = $(this).parent().next().stop(true, true).slideToggle();;
        allPanels.not($target).stop(true, true).slideUp();
        return false;
    });

})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LbU4c/)

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function ($) 
{
  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function () 
   {
    allPanels.not( $(this).parent().next().stop(true, true).slideToggle()).stop(true,true).slideUp();
    return false;
   });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slideToggle()`

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/b4g9U/4/